# Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient) deprecated

Tags: android, google-drive-api, deprecated

While trying to set up the Google Drive API for Android, In this line

```
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
```

I'm getting that both, `DriveApi` and `getAppFolder` are deprecated.

What should I replace it with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deprecation was officially announced in [this reference page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi):

> This interface was deprecated. Gain access to the Drive API with one
>   of the Drive#get*Client() methods instead.

This was replaced with methods like [getDriveClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive) and you can see sample code demos in [googledrive/android-demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java):

```
private void initializeDriveClient(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {
        mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(getApplicationContext(), signInAccount);
        mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getApplicationContext(), signInAccount);
        onDriveClientReady();
    }
```

Check the [Drive API for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) for more info.