# How can I correct the warning "Drive.API is deprecated"?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

Here is my code that creates a GoogleApiClient instance that connects with the Google Drive service:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* 
                OnConnectionFailedListener */)

            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)

            .build();
```

with

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.0'
```

I got the warning

**'API' is deprecated**

How can I prevent this warning ?

Comment: To ignore warnings use this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770754/android-studio-ignore-deprecated

Comment: You can use this to fix the warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835372/drive-driveapi-getappfoldermgoogleapiclient-deprecated since its deprecated you need to use these driver functions

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arshad, the whole set of API is deprecated, let's do it again the new way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global answer of Google Drive API deprecated was given there  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843323/9581467
with appropriate links for documentation

Thanks @Arshad and @noogui